# UINavigationBar.layer.contents not working in IOS5, Any idea why?

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios5, xcode4.2, uinavigationbar

I am using the following line of code to place image to show background of a UINavigationBar, it works fine in IOS4 but not working on devices with IOS5.

```
 UINavigationBar.layer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"header_bg_green.png"].CGImage;
```

Also when i test it in IOS 5 Simulator it do not show image for UINavigationBar layer.

Please help.

Thanks,
Jigar

Comment: [Here is complete implementation of CustomNavigationBar](https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/blob/master/CustomBackButton/Classes/CustomNavigationBar.m) works in both iOS 4 and iOS 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS 5 they changed the way you do custom backgrounds in navigation bars. The method is:

```
- (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)backgroundImage forBarMetrics:(UIBarMetrics)barMetrics
```

If you want to support both iOS 4 and iOS 5 in your app, you'll need to do some kind of check (such as using `respondsToSelector`), and then conditionally use either the old way or this method.